# What is the ratio of the relative minimum to the relative maximum value of a cubic?

Tags: polynomials, cubics, ratio

What is the ratio of the relative minimum to the relative maximum value of the general cubic polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$? Consider only cubic functions with $3$ real, unique roots.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified the question.

Comment: You can do this.  Nothing more is involved than locating the relative extrema by solving a quadratic.  To determine which critical point is the relative minimum and which the relative maximum requires considering the cases of sign for leading coefficient $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the derivative, $3ax^2+2bx+c=0$ to find relative extrema. Solving for $x$, we find that $$x_{extrema}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{{{b}^{2}}-3ac}}{3a}$$
Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Now, we just need to simplify
$$\frac{f\left(x_{extrema}^+\right)}{f\left(x_{extrema}^-\right)}$$
which comes out to
$$-\frac{-2 {{b}^{3}}+9 a b c+\sqrt{{{b}^{2}}-3 a c} \left( 6 a c-2 {{b}^{2}}\right) -27 {{a}^{2}} d}{27 {{a}^{2}} d+\sqrt{{{b}^{2}}-3 a c} \left( 6 a c-2 {{b}^{2}}\right) -9 a b c+2 {{b}^{3}}}$$
It is worthwhile to note that the constraint ${27 {{a}^{2}} d+\sqrt{{{b}^{2}}-3 a c} \left( 6 a c-2 {{b}^{2}}\right) -9 a b c+2 {{b}^{3}}}\ne0$ is satisfied by the restriction that the cubic must have $3$ distinct real roots. As well, the constraint $3a\ne0$ is also satisfied by the fact that the polynomial must be a cubic.

The above expression can be simplified with a number of substitutions.
Let $\alpha=2b^3-9abc+27a^2d$ and $\beta=\sqrt{b^2-3ac}\left(6ac-2b^2\right)$.

Then, the ratio of the relative minimum to relative maximum of the cubic is simply $$-\frac{\beta-\alpha}{\beta+\alpha}$$

Comment: Did you add this after my answer ?

Comment: No, this was the first answer posted on this question.

Comment: So, we have been typing at the same time. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici : This simple answer reminds me that I have seen a long time ago that this ratio can be transformed into the ratio of the largest eigenvalue over the smallest eigenvalue of a certain matrix associated with a certain quadratic form (i.e., linked to its condition number), but I dont remember more than that...